# Can't load form from my Install Profile

Tags: 9, installation-profiles

I have a `WelcomeForm` inside my `src` folder in my install profile. My install profile is located inside web/profiles folder and is correctly selected by default during install.

However, I added an install task (inside my `business_profile.install` file) as so...

```
function business_profile_install_tasks_alter() {
  $new_task['install_welcome'] = [
    'display' => TRUE, 
    'type' => 'form',
    'function' => '\Drupal\business_profile\src\Form\WelcomeForm'
  ];
```

But the installer shows an error -

```
InvalidArgumentException. Form \Drupal\business_profile\src\Form\WelcomeForm is not a valid form in... ->getFormId()
```

My `WelcomeForm` extends FormBase and implements `getFormId()` returning a valid string. Also implements `buildForm()` and returns a valid $form array. Nothing wrong anywhere.And here's my WelcomeForm...

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\business_profile\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

class WelcomeForm extends FormBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'business_profile_installer_welcome_form';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $form['#title'] = $this->t('Welcome');

    $form['actions'] = [
      '#type' => 'actions'
    ];

    $form['actions']['save'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Save and continue'),
      '#button_type' => 'primary',
      '#submit' => ['::submitForm'],
    ];
    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form_state->setRedirect('<front>');
  }
  
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {}

}
```

And I can confirm the form is saved as `web/profiles/business_profile/src/Form/WelcomeForm.php`

What could possibly make Drupal installer not to see my Form then? Is this an autoload issue (just suspecting) - but I thought files in a selected install profile (distribution) are autoloaded?

Spent a few days on this, any help pls guys?

Comment: Showing us the code for WelcomeForm would help.

Comment: Right, cilefen. I've adjusted the question to include the form code. Thanks for your response.

Comment: The exception is thrown by this function: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormBuilder.php/function/FormBuilder%3A%3AgetFormId/9.4.x

Answer (score 3):

Ok, guys - I just sorted this out! But you have all been awesome, thanks a bunch! Following leymanxx suggestions, I replaced `'function' => '\Drupal\business_profile\src\Form\WelcomeForm'` with `'function' => WelcomeForm::class`, and then made an import on top.

I also had to add an autoload entry to my `web/profiles/business_profile/composer.json` file like this...

```
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Drupal\\business_profile\\": "src"
        }
    },
```

I then did a composer update and saw `Generating autoload files` message on my terminal. And bam!! Form shows up.

Now I get to design my form.
Thanks a bunch @leymanxx, @cilefen, @Tritof and everyone else that helped out on this.

Answer (score 1):

See [#2965929](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2965929); it's probably the class name not matching the file name. The file needs to be named WelcomeForm.php.

Please also remove the `src` from the function assignment. It needs to be `'function' => '\Drupal\business_profile\Form\WelcomeForm'`.

Comment: The file is named WelcomeForm.php. I've confirmed this.

Comment: @ilechcod – Ah got it! It needs to be `'function' => '\Drupal\business_profile\Form\WelcomeForm'` without the `src`

Comment: Thanks leymannx - this was definitely one of the issues.